# MySQL query to remove certain email address, all follow similar pattern

Tags: mysql

Wondered if someone could help me write a MySQL query. I noticed in my email database I have a huge amount of users who got past my automated entry checks who I want to flag. They are all of the form `abcdef123@hotmail.com` where `abcdef` are random names of variable length, then a 3 digit number.

I have a field in my table called `fld_bad`, which I want to change to 1 in the query.

So something like

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET fld_bad = "1" WHERE fld_email .....
```

Obviously the `.....` is where my knowledge is failing me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the mysql regexp command to do this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

`UPDATE tbl_users SET fld_bad = "1" WHERE fld_email REGEXP '[A-Za-z]+[0-9]{3}@hotmail\\.com' = 1;`

Comment: Started to write essentially the same response. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
UPDATE tbl_users 
SET fld_bad = "1" 
WHERE fld_email REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit]]{3}@hotmail\\.com'
```